# How do I add my new Paragraph type to a content type?

Tags: 7, nodes, paragraphs

I've made a new Paragraph type and it appears as an option in the Basic Page content type, but I'd also like it to appear in another content type.

Would anyone know where I set this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was missing a step:

1. Structure>>Content Types
2. Edit the content type you want to add the Paragraph to
3. Go to Manage Fields tab
4. Find the Paragraphs entry in the list and click edit
5. Check your bundle from the list